# как с помощью JavaScript определить размер экрана?

Tags: javascript

Есть *javascript*-код, который должен выполняться при максимальном размере окна браузера 768px и меньше.

при увеличения размера больше 768px скрипт не должен выполняться.

Comment: Спасибо ребята, я уже разобрался

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужны внешние размеры окна (со скроллбарами, рамкой и прочим), то:

```
window.outerWidth
```

Если внутренние, за [вычетом всяких рамок](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp) (но без вычета скроллов):

```
var width = window.innerWidth
    || document.documentElement.clientWidth
    || document.body.clientWidth;
```

Comment: @Regent я не из комментария код брал :) просто скопипастил с w3schools и чуть подровнял. Коммент появился когда я уже палец над save занес. сорри если что :(

Comment: Я и не рассчитывал разместить этот код как ответ. Потому что, по сути, я лишь скопировал код с чужого ответа. На SO я бы проголосовал за закрытие вопроса как повтора, а тут вот и непонятно как поступить.

Comment: @Regent оставлять ссылку на английский вопрос. я обычно в футере оставляю, в <sub></sub>. дописывать текст на русском, чтобы не было уже совсем чистой копипасты. тут [на мете обсуждались межязыковые ссылки](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431/), но они все равно подразумевают копирование и перевод ответа.